# Run Multithread and Asyncio together

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, httprequest, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

i am trying to make a python program that makes http requests and parses the data from the response with asyncio and aiohttp. The program takes as input a list of urls that can reach even more than 300/400 elements and should make requests as fast as possible. Since asyncio runs on only one thread, I was thinking of splitting the list into sublists and starting a thread for each sublist with asyncio and aiohttp, but adding the ThreadPoolExecutor I get coroutine and futures errors. How can I use Thread and asyncio together? I leave the code below.

```
async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
        # if response.status == 200:
            html_body = await response.json()
            url = url.split('/')[-2]
            file_name = url if url != 'services' else 'live'
            async with aiofiles.open(f'{output_dir}/{file_name}.json', 'w') as f:
                await f.write(json.dumps(html_body, indent=4))
            return html_body
            
async def fetch_with_sem(sem, session, url):
    async with sem:
        return await fetch(url, session)

async def run(url, session, sem):
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_with_sem(sem, session, url)) for url in url]
    page_content = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    return page_content

async def main(urls):
    number = len(urls) // 10 + 1
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(50)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit_per_host=30, limit=50, ttl_dns_cache=100)
    headers = {
        'user-agent': get_user_agent(),
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': "macOS",
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'x-eb-accept-language': 'it_IT',
        'x-eb-marketid': '5',
        'x-eb-platformid': '1',
    }
    async with ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=connector, headers=headers) as session:
        if isinstance(urls, list):
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25) as executor:
                page_content = [executor.submit(
                                                run, urls[number * i : number * (i + 1)], session, sem
                                                ).result() for i in range(10)
                                ]
        else:
            tasks = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_with_sem(sem, session, urls))]
            page_content = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        return page_content
```

the problem is given from executor.submit and got this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'wait' was never awaited
  page_content = [executor.submit(asyncio.wait(run), urls[number * i : number * (i + 1)], session, sem).result() for i in range(10)]
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/federikowsky/Desktop/Python/Scraping/SureBet/prova.py", line 123, in <module>
    x = asyncio.run(main(link))
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/federikowsky/Desktop/Python/Scraping/SureBet/prova.py", line 110, in main
    page_content = [executor.submit(asyncio.wait(run), urls[number * i : number * (i + 1)], session, sem).result() for i in range(10)]
  File "/Users/federikowsky/Desktop/Python/Scraping/SureBet/prova.py", line 110, in <listcomp>
    page_content = [executor.submit(asyncio.wait(run), urls[number * i : number * (i + 1)], session, sem).result() for i in range(10)]
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

Comment: threads don't run multiple parallel processes either so you will get no gain from this change. Try multiprocessing instead, however worth checking to see if aiosync and aiohttp are actually as slow as you think first.

Comment: ok but how should i write the code to run it with multiprocessing?

Comment: Don't. Alternatively, [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: how can I lighten the workload on a single thread then?

Comment: Start with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Clear the error on [wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives), where is this? Have a look at your line ```url)) for url in url```. You've merged the file io with the aiohttp session io which places two distinct io types into one function.

Comment: So how can I fix it?